# Social connect (oauth) avatar best practices. Copy or link?

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth

I use oauth with twitter/facebook/google+ to allow users of our website to signup and signin. We display the users' avatar with user generated content across the site.

With facebook the original image keeps the same url when the user change it (http://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/picture?type=normal)
But on twitter every image used as avatar has a different url (http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/[slug]/[other_slug]_reasonably_small.jpeg)

What is the best practice to display these images, and what is allowed by the terms of use.

1- Download a copy of the image and create a media on our server, then users can change it as they see fit?

2- Always link to original image and update the link in user profile on sync?